# DateTime.Parse, Latvian culture settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, globalization, cultureinfo

I am sending in a string in `dd/MM/yyyy` format, which is then being parsed into `lv-LV` culture as set per the web.config globalization setting.

I am then comparing the date to `DateTime.Now` to see if it is in the past.

The problem is, `DateTime.Parse` converts my string to `dd.MM.yyyy` format, but DateTime.Now has `MM.dd.yyyy` format, so the comparison always fails.

Why would `DateTime.Now` be different to the output from `DateTime.Parse`, on the same thread culture?

Thanks!

(Update) This is the code I am using:

InputText contains input from a form in DD.MM.YYYY format

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(InputText, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
// Check it's not in the past
this.IsValid = (date.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) > 0);
```

[DateTime.Now] in this context is in MM.DD.YYYY format using lv-LV cultureInfo
[date] is in DD.MM.YYYY format after the DateTime.Parse

Comment: I think you need to show us some more complete code; a `DateTime` (such as `.Now`, or the result of a `.Parse`) doesn't *have* a format of its own - ddmm versus mmdd is a property of *string representations*, not of `DateTime` values themselves.

Comment: are you comparing two dates as strings? if you are comparing two datetime structures, it should not matter what culture the toString is representing.

Answer (score 2):

A `DateTime` does not have formatting - it is simply a point in time.

If you are viewing it, that means you are outputting it. Use the correct culture to output the date.

[`DateTime.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a095fsay.aspx) has overloads that take a format provider such as a `CultureInfo`:

```
string formatted = DateTime.ToString(new CultureInfo("lv-LV"));
```

If not specified (in code or configuration), the default system culture will be used (or `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, in some cases).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to compare the 2 dates, you don't need to convert to string first.

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse(myDateAsString);//with the correct locale to ensure it's correctly parsed
if (myDate < DateTime.Now)
{
  //it's in the past
}
```